# Create pdf through java.io

Tags: java

I tried creating a pdf file out of another one(in my local drive) using java.io. The thing is a file with a .pdf extension got created but im unable to open the file, it says the file is already in use and most importantly the size of the file is too large and it keeps on increasing (origin file size : 5,777kB and the newly created one file size as of now is 38,567kB). Im not that much of skilled java programmer but still i would appreciate if anyone can give me an explanation ..

```
String path = "D:\\priya_Docs\\Android pdfs\\Professional_Android_Application_Development.pdf";
        File file = new File(path);
        System.out.println("Located a file " + file.isFile());
        String filesArray = file.getPath();
        File getFile = file.getAbsoluteFile();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(getFile);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
                "D:\\priya_Docs\\Androiddoc.pdf");
        for (int b = fis.read(); b != -1;) {
            fos.write(b);
        }
```

Comment: Do you close output stream when you finished writing?

Comment: You're trying to copy a file byte by byte. That's very slow and inefficient.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not writing anything else to the FileOutputStream at a later point of time? You'd better flush and close the stream right after the for loop to ensure nothing else gets written to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you meet the two problems
first,you have to close the resource: fis and fos,or it will say the file already in use
second,you have to use the byte[] to receive the data because pdf file is organized in byte arrays

```
            String path = "D:\\priya_Docs\\Android pdfs\\Professional_Android_Application_Development.pdf";
    File file = new File(path);
    System.out.println("Located a file " + file.isFile());
    String filesArray = file.getPath();
    File getFile = file.getAbsoluteFile();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(getFile);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
            "D:\\priya_Docs\\Androiddoc.pdf");
    byte[] buff=new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while((len=fis.read(buff))>=0) {
        fos.write(buff,0,len);
    }

    fis.close();
    fos.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ! so u mean to say its better to read the file into a byte buffer than read and write through an int.

Answer (score 2):

Simple use,

[`FileUtils.copyFile()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29)